# Where's the const SOMAXCONN defined in c?

Tags: c, network-programming

I thought it was retrieve at compile time from `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`,but after I modified it to `1024` by `echo 1024 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`,the `SOMAXCONN` is still `128` in my programe.

```
    printf("---------------set socket to listen,maxconn is %d--------------\r\n\r\n", SOMAXCONN);
    // set socket to listen
    if (listen(sock_listen, SOMAXCONN) != 0)...
```

I've checked `sys/socket.h` but it's not there...

Where/how can I change its value?

Comment: It should be in `tcp.h`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198564/programatically-evaluating-the-value-of-somaxconn-to-set-the-listen-backlog-para

Comment: @Evan Mulawski ,just checked,not there...

Comment: How about `/etc/sysctl.conf`? It should be under `kern.ipc.somaxconn`. You can use http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl to programmatically change the value.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski ,I decide to hardcode the number in my programe `listen(sock_listen, 1024)`.`sysctl` is a bash command,how can I use it in my programe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system it's defined in `bits/socket.h`

```
/* Maximum queue length specifiable by listen.  */
#define SOMAXCONN   128
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198564/programatically-evaluating-the-value-of-somaxconn-to-set-the-listen-backlog-para), you don't need to use SOMAXCONN. Just specify number you want and it will be limited to actual maximum.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 12.04, it is in /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h. SOMAXCONN is defined by http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux it seems to be here:

```
$ find /usr/include -name \*.h -exec grep SOMAXCONN {} /dev/null \;
/usr/include/bits/socket.h:#define SOMAXCONN    128
```

Under Mac OS X and BSD it seems to be here:

```
$ find /usr/include -name \*.h -exec grep SOMAXCONN {} /dev/null \;
/usr/include/sys/socket.h:#define   SOMAXCONN   128
```

i.e. in both cases it's `socket.h` but they live in different locations on different operating systems it seems.